# $(y-\sqrt{x})(y-\sqrt{-x})=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

$(y-x)(y+x)=0$ is a graph that combines $y-x=0$ and $y+x=0$.

I understood that by multiplication 2 functions (or more) that in the form of $a=0$ and $b=0$, so $a\cdot b=0$ will be the 2 functions. (Please explain it to me more, and why it happens).

So my question is why: $(y-\sqrt{x})(y-\sqrt{-x})=0$ is not a graph that includes $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\sqrt{-x}$
How can I  get to a $y$ and $x$ form which will give me a graph that includes $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\sqrt{-x}$ ?

[image: This is what I talk about]
*Help me wil the correct tags

Thanks

Comment: Is $y$ supposed to be a complex number?

Comment: I don't talk about complex numbers, I mean $y$ like $f(x)$. I hope you understand me

Comment: Well, for $x \neq 0$ either $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{-x}$ is undefined then?

Comment: Oh I understand... Is it possible to make a form that will give the graph?

Comment: *Which graph?* $ $

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the graph"? To define a function you have to define a domain, it's absolutely crucial. The domain is part of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing what you want: Probably, you want to graph the $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:(-\infty,0] \to \mathbb{R}$ of the functions $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{-x}$. To define a function that kind of "graphs" both functions, you can define
$$ h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ h(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{x} \quad &\text{ if } x \geq 0, \\ \sqrt{-x} &\text{ if } x <0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: ...which is basically the same that Andrei proposes. Only that Andrei's term is much shorter, while mine basically uses the definition of $| \cdot |$.

Comment: How could I go from this from to the shorter form?

Comment: As I've said, it is literally the definition of an absolute value. You just plug in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Because$\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt{-x}$ are not both real numbers except for $0$. You can use $y=\sqrt{|x|}$

Comment: How did you know $y=\sqrt{|x|}$ is the correct one?

Comment: You wanted to take a square root of a number, and you used $-x$ on the negative side, and $x$ on the positive side. That's the absolute value

Comment: What would you do if I want to combine $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{-2x}$ ?

Comment: You follow @Kezer procedure

Comment: I mean as shorter from, not the longer.

Comment: You can not always get a short form :) Why do you even absolutely need a short one? A longer one is absolutely fine.